# Can Navy WSO use autopilot to fly to safety?

Tags: military

If pilot becomes incapacitated, can Navy WSO use autopilot to fly to a safe place to eject?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On the F15-E, can the WSO take over if the pilot is incapacitated?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/on-the-f15-e-can-the-wso-take-over-if-the-pilot-is-incapacitated)

Comment: Which aircraft? Some models have back seat controls, others (most for the USN) don't. The autopilot is not a taxi app with a home button, it just keeps the plane stable.

Comment: Not a dupe, for 2 reasons... the suggested question is all about the F-15E, while this question asks about Navy flying. Second, this question asks specifically about autopilot usage, which isn't addressed in the suggested question.

Comment: Reason for question: Ejecting in friendly territory at safe altitude is preferable, so do Navy WSO's have some means by which to climb, and bring the aircraft back to friendly territory, before ejecting crew? Only reason I've been given so far is that the pilot is rarely incapacitated, but given the seeming minimal expense of implementing a simple programmable autopilot, especially on fly-by-wire aircraft, why wouldn't the Navy want both crew members to have this capability?

Comment: Well, if he has flight controls, it'd be pretty easy to do that without an autopilot.